# Last word is Failing ...?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

i am having problems with the last word, it seems to miss out 1 last step.

Input:

`JXJIAA`

OUTPUT:

`lowercase: 0.00 uppercase: 77.78`

when it supposed to be

`lowercase: 0.00 uppercase: 100.00?`

The Program works if there is another line in the text file, but I want it to work without the extra line, I am thinking i has something to do with this: "while (line[x] != 10);" but don't know what to do?
Is there any way in which I can improve this code. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *fr; 

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]){
    char line[1024];
    double uppercase = 0, lowercase = 0;
    int x = 0;
    fr = fopen ("PercenUpLow.txt", "rt");
    while(fgets(line, 1024, fr) != NULL){
        do{
            if ((line[x] >= 'A') && (line[x] <= 'Z')){
                uppercase += 1;
            }else if ((line[x] >= 'a') && (line[x] <= 'z')){
                lowercase += 1;    
            }
                x+=1;
            }while (line[x] != 10);
            printf("lowercase: %0.2f ", (lowercase / x) * 100);
            printf("uppercase: %0.2f \n", (uppercase / x) * 100);
            lowercase = 0;
            uppercase = 0;
            x = 0;
        }    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Example:**

Input:

`HeLo`

Output:

`Uppercase: 50.00 Lowercase: 50.00`

Comment: Where exactly do you get a segmentation fault and have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Test if `fr`  is NULL after `fopen` and if yes display an error message and don't go further.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you should write `'A'` and `'Z'` inspead of `65` and `90` etc. Also you program is not correctly indented which harms to the readability.

Comment: "any recommendations would be appreciated" Is sadly a way of asking a question which can't be answered in a way SO expects a Answer to be designed like.

Comment: @UnholySheep im using a website called codeeval, and it compiles it itself, so i cant really tell, sorry :\

Comment: @MattSolo then just get a compiler+debugger on your machine and try the code there? Online Compilers are not suited for programming, especially if they don't even give you basic debugging support, like this one seems to do. However Michael Walz's suggestion seems to be the most likely cause (especially since I guess that that website does not have access to the file you are trying to open)

Comment: @MattSolo : I don't knopw copdeeval (which is located where BTW ?) How do you expect codeeval to get acces to your "PercenUpLow.txt" file ?

Comment: @UnholySheep thank you so much!, yes the website didn't have access to the file i was passing in, and realised i had to add "argv[1]" instead of "PercenUpLow.txt", but now i am having problems with the last word, it seems to miss out 1 last step. INPUT: JXJIAA, OUTPUT: lowercase: 0.00 uppercase: 77.78 when it supposed to be uppercase: 100.00 when it

Comment: @MichaelWalz I don't know, i thought i may of created a text document with the same name as my program which was called PercenUpLow.c. Obviously i was wrong, and feel really stupid.

Comment: @MattSolo As this is a new problem, unrelated to this question, you should probably open a new question (or rather try to debug it on your own Machine first, as that way you will get some practice on the most time consuming aspect of programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *fr; 

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]){
  char line[1024];
  double uppercase = 0, lowercase = 0;
  int x = 0;
  fr = fopen ("PercenUpLow.txt", "rt");
  if (fr == NULL) {
    printf ("Can't open file") ;
    return EXIT_FAILURE ;
  }
  while(fgets(line, 1024, fr) != NULL) {
    do {
      if ((line[x] >= 'A') && (line[x] <= 'Z')){
        uppercase += 1;
      }else if ((line[x] >= 'a') && (line[x] <= 'z')){
        lowercase += 1;    
      }
      x+=1;
    } while (line[x] != '\n' && line[x] != 0);

    printf("lowercase: %0.2f ", (lowercase / x) * 100);
    printf("uppercase: %0.2f \n", (uppercase / x) * 100);
    lowercase = 0;
    uppercase = 0;
    x = 0;
  }    
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I changed this line:

```
     } while (line[x] != '\n' && line[x] != 0);
```

If the file is not terminated by a `\n`, then the last line read is not terminated by a `\n` either (seems obvious) and you are reading further than the end of the line, leading to undefined behaviour.

I also test if the file could be opened correctly.

You should definitely learn how to use a debugger.